# How to measure the spacing between controls of a NSRunAlertPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsrunalertpanel

How can I find out the number of pixel position between the controls of a NSRunAlertPanel.
In Interface Builder we can use the Option+Mouse to find the pixel length.Please help.

Comment: First, why do you want to know this? What are you trying to do? Second, why are you using `NSRunAlertPanel()`? `NSAlert` is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to share the answer,If really need to measure the AlertPanel spacing there is an easy way.

When the Alert is running,press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>,drag between the controls,cursor will display the length and width in pixels.